# Unable to find file system erro in Debian Live CD over PXE

Tags: debian, boot, kernel, pxe-boot, live-cd

I'm having trouble setting up a Debian Live CD to run over HTTP with PXE.
I can not see the problem, apache logs indicate 200 to request that accesses the filesystem.squashfs.

The console looks like this:

[image: My screen]

My pxelinux.cfg / default

```
LABEL CLIENT
 MENU DEFAULT
 MENU LABEL Debian 8.5 Live
 KERNEL systems/debian/live/vmlinuz
 INITRD systems/debian/live/initrd.img
 APPEND dhcp ethdevice=eth0 boot=live fetch=http://10.0.0.2/debian/live/filesystem.squashfs
```

My Debian Live CD version is 8.5

Anyone have any idea what might be going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case the HTTP provisioning needs to move the `filesystem.squashfs` file to RAM. That file is pretty big and your client is running out of memory. That's what your print-screen says. If you run your client from a VM just give it more memory, if your client is real you need bigger memory chips.

Comment: Really! I do not believe that was stamped on my face all the time lol.
Is there any possibility to reduce the size of the filesystem?

Comment: there's not an easy way to reduce filesystem.squashfs. You could create a custom live version; a long and tedious process though